# Inserting Multiple Select Value to database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to input multiple select values in Database. Here is my demo code:

https://jsfiddle.net/wuarv946/

My controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $data= array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'foods' => $this->input->post('foods')
    );
    $this->food_model->add_food($data);
}
```

My model:

```
public function add_food($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('order_items', $data);
}
```

It only insert the last value of select. How to fix that.

Comment: Can you post `var_dump($data)`?

Comment: Have you specified 'multiple' attribute in select eg:  <select multiple> </select>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to loop your foodlist.

My controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $food_list = $this->input->post('foods');
    foreach($food_list as $food) {
    $data= array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'foods' => $food
    );
    $this->db->insert('order_items', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: @russell see my update. try to do that loop. if it doesn't work let me know what does var_dump($this->input->post('foods');

Answer (score 2):

Try this..
Change select dropdown name with `name="foods[]"` .

```
<select name="foods[]" class="selectpicker" multiple title="Choose Foods" multiple data-max-options="2" data-live-search="true">
  <option value="1">Mustard</option>
  <option value="2">Ketchup</option>
  <option value="3">Relish</option>
</select>
```

Controller

```
public function create()
{
    $data= array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'foods' => implode(",",$this->input->post('foods')) // Store foods with comma separate 
    );
    $this->food_model->add_food($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this in select `name="foods[]"`

try controller like this

```
public function create()
{
    $foods = $this->input->post('foods');
    $name= $this->input->post('name');
    $data = array();
    foreach( $foods as $k => $v){
      $data[$k]['name']=$name;
      $data[$k]['foods']=$v;
    }

    $this->food_model->add_food($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your form html code.

1) You have not specified form post method so its taking by default `"get"` method and you are trying to get values using `post()`.

2) You have set the select multiple but did not make its name as array `foods[]`.

Do like below:

```
<form method="post">
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="name" placeholder="Enter name" class="form-control">
<select name="foods[]" class="selectpicker" multiple title="Choose Foods" multiple data-max-options="2" data-live-search="true">
  <option value="1">Mustard</option>
  <option value="2">Ketchup</option>
  <option value="3">Relish</option>
</select>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And change controller as below:

```
public function create()
{
    $foods = $this->input->post('foods');
    $name= $this->input->post('name');
    $data = array();
    foreach( $foods as $key => $value){
      $data[$key]['name']=$name;
      $data[$key]['foods']=$value;
    }

    $this->food_model->add_food($data);
```

Hope this will clear you and solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$this->db->insert_batch('order_items', $data);
```

[Codeigniter Inserting Data](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert#inserting-data)

Answer (score 0):

You need to batch insert e.g

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date'), ('Another title', 'Another name', 'Another date')
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting without cycle is always a great idea. The right way is to using array of associative arrays and insert them using `insert_batch` Active Record function.

Here is the example of that:

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'Title Text' ,
      'name' => 'Name Text' ,
      'date' => 'Date'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Title Text 1' ,
      'name' => 'Name Text 1' ,
      'date' => 'Date 1'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```